CreateSession and JoinSession debugging
First question on stack overflow. I was sent here via Reddit.
A bit of background, I'm following Stephen Ulibarris course on making a multiplayer shooter. Where I'm at, I've created a plug in with which I can host games, and join games. I'd like to modify the plugin to allow the host to input a custom game name, and for the person joining, to type a customgame name and join via that.
So I've tried a few things.
I thought I could Create a text widget that would allow me to input some text, and save that as an FName, and pass that on to my CreateSession function.
void UMultiplayerSessionsSubsystem::CreateSession(int32 NumPublicConnections, FString MatchType, FName HostName)
{
    if (!SessionInterface.IsValid())
        {
            return;
        }
auto ExistingSession = SessionInterface->GetNamedSession(HostName);
    if (ExistingSession != nullptr)
        {
            SessionInterface->DestroySession(HostName);
        }
    //Store the delegate in a FDelegatehandle so we can later remove it from the delegate list.
CreateSessionCompleteDelegateHandle =   SessionInterface->AddOnCreateSessionCompleteDelegate_Handle(CreateSessionCompleteDelegate);

    
LastSessionSettings = MakeShareable(new FOnlineSessionSettings());
LastSessionSettings->bIsLANMatch = IOnlineSubsystem::Get()->GetSubsystemName() == "Null" ? true : false;
LastSessionSettings->NumPublicConnections = NumPublicConnections;
LastSessionSettings->bAllowJoinInProgress = true;
LastSessionSettings->bAllowJoinViaPresence = true;
LastSessionSettings->bUseLobbiesIfAvailable = true;
LastSessionSettings->bShouldAdvertise = true;
LastSessionSettings->bUsesPresence = true;
LastSessionSettings->Set(FName("MatchType"), MatchType, EOnlineDataAdvertisementType::ViaOnlineServiceAndPing);

LastSessionSettings->Set(FName("SESSION_NAME"),HostName.ToString(), EOnlineDataAdvertisementType::ViaOnlineServiceAndPing);
        
const ULocalPlayer* LocalPlayer = GetWorld()->GetFirstLocalPlayerFromController();
    if(!SessionInterface->CreateSession(*LocalPlayer->GetPreferredUniqueNetId(), HostName, *LastSessionSettings))
    {
        SessionInterface->ClearOnCreateSessionCompleteDelegate_Handle(CreateSessionCompleteDelegateHandle);
        //Broadcast our own customDelegate
        MultiplayerOnCreateSessionComplete.Broadcast(false);
    }   
}

I thought What I could do is pass that in, and Set The FNAME to the parameter that I input, but that didnt work.
This is the Join Session Function.

void UMultiplayerSessionsSubsystem::JoinSession(const FOnlineSessionSearchResult& SessionResult)
{
    if(!SessionInterface.IsValid())
    {
        MultiplayerOnJoinSessionComplete.Broadcast(EOnJoinSessionCompleteResult::UnknownError);
        if(GEngine)
            {
                GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 1.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("SessionInterface Is not Valid"));
            }
        return;
    }
JoinSessionCompleteDelegateHandle =     SessionInterface->AddOnJoinSessionCompleteDelegate_Handle(JoinSessionCompleteDelegate);

const ULocalPlayer* LocalPlayer = GetWorld()->GetFirstLocalPlayerFromController();
    
    if(!SessionInterface->JoinSession(*LocalPlayer->GetPreferredUniqueNetId(), NAME_GameSession, SessionResult))
    {
        SessionInterface->ClearOnJoinSessionCompleteDelegate_Handle(JoinSessionCompleteDelegateHandle);
        MultiplayerOnJoinSessionComplete.Broadcast(EOnJoinSessionCompleteResult::UnknownError);
    }
}

This is the Find Session Function

void UMultiplayerSessionsSubsystem::FindSessions(int32 MaxSearchResult)
{
    if(!SessionInterface.IsValid())
    {
        if (GEngine)
        {
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 1.0f, FColor::Cyan, TEXT("OnlineSessionInterface Is not Valid"));
        }
        return;
    }

    FindSessionsCompleteDelegateHandle =  SessionInterface->AddOnFindSessionsCompleteDelegate_Handle(FindSessionsCompleteDelegate);
    LastSessionSearch = MakeShareable(new FOnlineSessionSearch());
    LastSessionSearch->MaxSearchResults = MaxSearchResult;
    LastSessionSearch->bIsLanQuery  = IOnlineSubsystem::Get()->GetSubsystemName() == "Null" ? true : false;
    LastSessionSearch->QuerySettings.Set(SEARCH_PRESENCE, true, EOnlineComparisonOp::Equals);

    const ULocalPlayer* LocalPlayer = GetWorld()->GetFirstLocalPlayerFromController();
    if(!SessionInterface->FindSessions(*LocalPlayer->GetPreferredUniqueNetId(),LastSessionSearch.ToSharedRef()))
    {
        SessionInterface->ClearOnFindSessionsCompleteDelegate_Handle(FindSessionsCompleteDelegateHandle);
        MultiplayerOnFindSessionsComplete.Broadcast(TArray<FOnlineSessionSearchResult>(), false);
        if(GEngine)
            {
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 1.0f, FColor::Cyan, TEXT("FindSessionFailed"));
            }
    }
    
}

